# hash password before submit form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm trying to hash the value of the password input field and put the hashed value back in the password field before submission.

I'm currently using:

```
$('#logForm').submit(function(){
    var passwd = $('#logPassword').val();
    passwd = $.sha256(passwd);
    $('#logPassword').val(passwd);
    return false;
});
```

I can't see why it's not working as the non hashed password is submitted...

Comment: Did you try just setting alerting the value of `passwd` after calling `sha256`? then you will be able to verify that the event handler actually executes and that the hashing function works.

Comment: I simply didn't include the script inside `$(document).ready(...);`. Stupid mistake :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You cannot set a password textbox on the client using JavaScript for security reasons. Stash the value you need in a hidden field.

Comment: This is not true. You can set the value of a password input in javascript.